# How do I share a variable from one script to another in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a simple clicker game which checks if a part is clicked and then will add 1 to a variable which will be displayed on a simple text gui on the screen with a script. However I can't really find a way to take the variable from the part script and take it to the gui script to put it in.

I used this script and a ClickDetector with this script.
`

```
local part = script.Parent
local click = part.ClickDetector
clicks = 0

local function onClick(player)
    clicks = clicks + 1
end

click.MouseClick:Connect(onClick)
```

`
It adds one to the clicks variable every time the part is clicked.

I used this script on the text gui to change the text shown to the clicks variable
`

```
local thistext = Instance.new("TextBox")

thistext.Text = tostring(clicks)
```

`
I was confused since I thought that clicks was a global variable and should've been recognised and after a quick google search I realised that global variables are only recognised in the same script and not others and when I run it the text is blank. I can't find any way to share the variable with the other script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Module script, as those are used for storing values server-side. Using require, you can get the module script from any script and see its contents (it defaults to a table)

[Doccumentation](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ModuleScript)

Answer (score 0):

For the click Detector Script do:

```
local Part = script.Parent
local click part.ClickDetector
clicks = 0

local function onClick() 
   clicks = clicks + 1
end

click.MouseClick:Connect function()
    
     onClick()

end)
```

You wrote the function inside of the "()" that was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If neither of those solutions work, I believe you can add a variable as an object under Workspace or wherever you want it, and it should be accessible from anywhere. I would put it somewhere server side, as an exploit could also access it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).